# Find greek letters with their translation in Elasticsearch (α as alpha)

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to search an index that contains many symbols and terms from chemical and biological analytics. It contains a lot of greek letters for various analytical methods. I would like to optimize for the following things:

- find `α` by searching `alpha`.
- find `Fe` by searching `iron`.

Do I need to create this mapping myself?

Comment: How about using a [synonyms token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html) to map all the 100+ values you need?

Comment: That should be the right one, but I didn't know what it was called. Thanks. Why not add it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a [synonyms token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html) to map all the 100+ values you need.

```
PUT index
{
    "settings" : {
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "synonyms" : {
                    "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
                    "filter" : ["synonym"]
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "synonym" : {
                    "type" : "synonym",
                    "synonyms" : [
                      "α => alpha",
                      "Fe => iron",
                      ...
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that instead of listing all synonyms inline, you can also store them in a file and point to it using the `synonyms_path` setting.

Comment: Thank you for the example. Really helpful!

Comment: Can you do something like this using search analyzer?

Comment: @RoyGranit feel free to create a new question explaining your needs

Comment: @Val see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61761287/how-to-replace-greek-letter-synonyms-using-search-analyzer-in-elasticsearch